# Trigger the contextmenu event

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube

I want to get the video id of a youtube ad.
I thought that I could get the video ID from the debug information of the youtube player.
So I tried to display the right-click menu.
But, oncontextmenu method of the player was null.

How can I display the right-click menu?

```
document.getElementById("movie_player").oncontextmenu()
// Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).oncontextmenu is not a function
```

In Chrome, I learned that getEventListeners is available in the devtools console.
But, the browser I mainly use is Firefox.
Even if I was using Chrome, it would be a pain to have to enter and run the devtools console every time you open youtube.

Comment: Did this code worked for you? - I'm not sure if I understand. If you want to keep trying, you need to watch the devtools (*either in Chrome or Firefox*) and expand the html/script tags - I don't know why is this behaviour, but, if you don't expand the tags, the data *inside* those tags are not searchable using the search box (*ctrl + f*).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.